# Windows Server 2008 IIS7 CSS Not Consistently Working

Tags: css, iis, windows-server-2008

I'm working on a site in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008, and everything was working perfectly until today. I was trying to add a small menu to a page, and all of a sudden the CSS stopped working. I refreshed the page a few times, and nothing. I viewed page source, and tried opening the CSS page via the link, and it was blank. I noticed that the server was low on space, so I did a little cleanup and refreshed the page, and it displayed correctly. I refreshed again, and it was back to not working. And that's what it's doing. It doesn't work for a while, and then on one page load, it works, and then stops working again. I didn't do anything to the CSS or the link to it. (I've tried loading it in Chrome and Firefox on my computer, and Chrome on the server)

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That's the code I'm using, and the file is in the same folder. I'm just baffled. I've never had my CSS code just stop working for seemingly no reason. My guess is that it has something to do with the server, but I'm fairly new to IIS, so I don't know what it would be. Any suggestions?

Solution:

The problem was that I had the style.css file in the root folder. I moved it and changed the path and fixed the issue.

Comment: that href doesn't look quite as solid as it should be IMHO.

Comment: Are you referring to the absence of "type='text/css'"?

Comment: No: more of a 'more specific' path. Your current path is suggesting it's on the root, rather than within a folder/etc

Comment: It is in the same folder that the web page is in. It was working fine for weeks prior to this happening so it would surprise me if that was the issue. But I'll try moving it and changing the path, because at this point I'm clueless.

Comment: Remember that time I said "I would be surprised if it worked"? Well color me surprised. What I'm wondering is why that worked. Any reason? I was always under the impression that if it was in the same folder you could just put the file name (Like a link to an alternate page). Is that not the case?

Comment: I've never have placed css in the root file, but instead in something like **site>style>site.css**.

Comment: Well now I know for future reference. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing your css file within a folder, rather than the root directory *may* do the trick for you.

So, rather than referencing your css like

```
href="style.css"
```

place it into a folder like: site>styles>style.css and make your href into:

```
"~/site/styles/style.css"
```

might be more beneficial to you (as personally I haven't placed my style sheets in the root folder for design reasons).